# Cannot connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse database-error "Incorrect syntax near 'ANSI_NULLS'"

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I could successfully deliver the new Azure SQL Data Warehouse database.

If Í try to connect to the SQL Data Warehouse Database, I receive following error message:

"Parse error at line: 1 ,column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'ANSI_NULLS'".

This happens in VS 2013 and VS 2015! The data load process with BCP to the SQL Data Warehouse database was successfully!

Thanks, Herbert

Answer (score 4):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not currently support setting ANSI_NULLS on (SET ANSI_NULL ON). You can simply remove that statement from your query and you should have success.

Additionally, make sure that you are running the June 2015 Preview of SSDT (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/06/24/ssdt-june-2015-preview.aspx). This has the supported SSDT capabilities for SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, when tried to [Use Visual Studio to query Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-query-visual-studio) 
 and selected my database.

The Workaround was to select master database, connect to it, then in top drop-down for the query change to my database.

Answer (score 1):

I think your connection isn't actually recognised as a SQL DW connection. I bet your query window is a .sql file, not a .dsql as it needs to be. If you connect as a .sql query, it will try to set various settings that aren't supported.

Go back into the Azure portal and use the link to connect using SSDT from there. You should get a connection in the SQL Server Explorer pane which looks different, and when you start a New Query based on it, you should get a .dsql window, not a .sql one.